# How to store multiple fields in redis and get top 10 result on basis of some field

Tags: python, csv, redis

I want to store multiple fields in `redis` from a `CSV` file

My `file.CSV` looks looks this.

```
SC_CODE,SC_NAME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,
500002,ABB LTD.,1372,1372.40,1339.95,1348.45,
500003,AEGIS LOGIS,275.00,275.00,261.50,266.70,
500008,AMAR RAJA BA,787.00,788.00,768.05,771.85,
```

I have written the following code to insert data into redis.

```
import csv
with open('file.CSV', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvReader)
    for row in csvReader:
        print ('HMSET {} open {} other \"{},{},{},{}\"\r'.format(row[0], row[2], row[1], row[3], row[4], row[5]))
```

and I am running this: `python redis.py | redis-cli --pipe`

which basically means on `redis-cli`

```
HMSET 500002 open 1372 other "ABB LTD.,1372.40,1339.95,1348.45"
```

But I am not able to know how should I get top 10 stocks on the basis of different fields from above. So I want to get the top 10, lowest 10 and sorting and other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that just by putting hashes in the keyspace; in redis, you have to maintain your own data structures suited to each kind of query that you want to do. In the case of top-N queries, the right data structure is a sorted set (the `Z` commands in redis). For instance, if you

> [ZADD](https://redis.io/commands/zadd) open 1372 50002

it will add the key `50002` to the set "open", with the score `1372`. Then you can

> [ZRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/zrange) open 0 9

or

> [ZREVRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrange) open -10 -1

to get the bottom 10 or top 10 keys based on their scores in the set "open". (Adding the `WITHSCORES` flag makes the query return the scores as well as the keys). Sorted sets also support [ZRANGEBYSCORE](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) to get all of the keys with scores between two values, etc... check the docs for more!

If you maintain one set like this for each column that you want to be able to query by, then you can do what you're after. You can still use hashes to store all the details for each object in one place so that you can look it up by ID once you find the IDs. [HMGET](https://redis.io/commands/hmget) is good for this.